# JavaScript Challenges that I can't solve

Tags: javascript

I am stuck with these two challenges:**Challenge 13** & **Challenge 15**. Can anybody help me??

**Challenge 13**

> You are provided with an object called `checkObj`. Using a `for...` in loop, determine if the object contains the property `foundNum`. If it exists, log `Found!` to the console, otherwise log, `Does not exist!` to the console.

```
let checkObj = {
  oddNum: 1,
  evenNum: 2,
  foundNum: 5,
  randomNum: 18
};

for (let prop in checkObj) {
  if(prop === 'foundNum') {
    console.log("Found!") 
  } else {
    console.log('Does not exist!')
  }
}
```

My result on this challenge prints "Does not exist!" for every property. It should instead print only once if there is none.

---

**Challenge14** <-- I solved it. This challenge is required for **Challenge 15**.

> You are provided with another empty array called objToArray. Using a for... in loop, fill the array with all of the numbers from the checkObj object from the previous challenge if they are greater than or equal to 2.

```
let objToArray = [];
for(let prop in checkObj){
  if(checkObj[prop] >= 2){
    objToArray.push(checkObj[prop]);
  }
}
console.log(objToArray);
```

---

**Chellenge 15**

> Using a for loop, iterate through the `objToArray` to determine if any of the numbers are divisible by 6. If there are any, log `true` to the console. If there aren't any, log `false` to the console.

```
for(let i = 0; i<objToArray.length; i++){
  if(objToArray[i]%6===0){
    console.log(true);
  } else{
    console.log(false);
  }
}
```

Same as challenge13, my code keeps printing false, but it only should print once if there aren't any number divisible by 6.

Comment: Instead of looping through and printing each time- why not set a boolean set initially to false. Set it to true if you find the element. After the loop completes check the condition of the boolean. If true: Print found. Else: print Not Found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing within the loop, keep a boolean variable and toggle it if property found and finally show the message based on the boolean value after the loop.

```
let checkObj = {
  oddNum: 1,
  evenNum: 2,
  foundNum: 5,
  randomNum: 18
};

let found = false;

for (let prop in checkObj) {
  // compare with the property name
  if(prop === 'foundNum') {
    // if found then update the boolean value
    found = true;
    // you can now break the for loop since property already found
    break;
  } 
}

// based on the boolean value show your message
console.log( found ? 'Found' : 'Not found');
```

```js
let checkObj = {
  oddNum: 1,
  evenNum: 2,
  foundNum: 5,
  randomNum: 18
};

let found = false;

for (let prop in checkObj) {
  // compare with the property name
  if (prop === 'foundNum') {
    // if found then update the boolean value
    found = true;
    // you can now break the for loop since property already found
    break;
  }
}

// based on the boolean value show your message
console.log(found ? 'Found' : 'Not found');
```

---

Same logic you need to use for the last challenge as well.

```
let possible = false;

for(let i = 0; i<objToArray.length; i++){
  // check number is divisible
  if(objToArray[i] % 6 === 0){
    // if divisible then updaet the boolean value
    possible = true;
    // break the for loop
    break;
  }
}

console.log(possible);
```

Comment: @andyahn : glad to help you :)